Wigner-Eckart theorem in classical physics?
The Wigner-Eckart theorem is a useful result in quantum physics and its many applications. Most presentations of this material in books on QM and online lecture notes seem to be variations on the same thing done in the Sakurai book, and that is fine.
However, given that it is a group theory result, is there some other nice application of it independent of QM? For example, in classical physics, stochastic dynamics (I'd imagine), etc?
It would be very useful to develop some intuition for it without mixing it with the rest of QM and relying on the bra-ket notation, as it is usually presented.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%E2%80%93Eckart_theorem  The Wigner–Eckart theorem is a theorem of representation theory and quantum mechanics. follow the links in the above link and you will see that the theorem is more general .

Not sure what you are trying to tell me. Is it that the W.E. theorem without QM does not make sense? Sure there are generalisations, but I was kind of hoping for a simplification (at least in terms of physics) rather than a more general version of the theorem.

I would be surprised to see an application outside quantum theory, maybe in geophysics/solar physics, where spherical harmonics have some use.

But QT motivated so much mathematics, I think some of it still has use only there.

@z.v. I meant that a general version exists which a smart researcher in mathematical subjects could find an application for.
